# Create shadow inside a tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

[image]

If not using an image?

```
   _t.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;

    _t.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-6, -6);

    _t.layer.shadowOpacity = 1;

    _t.clipsToBounds = false;
```

this can create outside shadow.

Comment: Add view with shadow below status bar or tab bar, and these views are above your tableView. [statusBar - shadowView - tableView]

Answer (score 1):

Add view with shadow below status bar or tab bar, and these views are above your tableView.

```
CGFloat statusBarHeight = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame].size.height;
CGFloat tabBarHeight = self.tabBarController.tabBar.bounds.size.height;

// status bar
UIView *statusBarShadowView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, statusBarHeight)];
statusBarShadowView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.view addSubview:statusBarShadowView];

CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer0 = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradientLayer0.frame = CGRectMake(0, statusBarHeight, self.view.bounds.size.width, 10);
gradientLayer0.colors = @[(id)[UIColor colorWithRed:0.91 green:0.91 blue:0.91 alpha:0.7].CGColor, (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0.7].CGColor];
[statusBarShadowView.layer insertSublayer:gradientLayer0 atIndex:0];


// tab bar
UIView *tabBarShadowView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - tabBarHeight, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, tabBarHeight)];
statusBarShadowView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.view addSubview:tabBarShadowView];

CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer1 = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradientLayer1.frame = CGRectMake(0, -10, self.view.bounds.size.width, 10);
gradientLayer1.colors = @[(id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0.7].CGColor, (id)[UIColor colorWithRed:0.91 green:0.91 blue:0.91 alpha:0.7].CGColor];
[tabBarShadowView.layer insertSublayer:gradientLayer1 atIndex:0];
```

[image]

Comment: can i just add to tableview because the tableview's frame will change.

Comment: You can, but the shadow will scroll with tableview, you will do some work to fixed shadow position.

Comment: i mean, it's a layer,can i put it on the tableview,then it will move with the tableview.

Comment: You can try it, just add the shadow layer to tableview's layer.